# Exception annotations for propagated exceptions

Tags: php, exception, phpdoc

Suppose I have a function `a` that throws an exception `$e`. Hence, according to `phpdoc` I should have an annotation `@throws` over the definition of `a`.

When I have another function `b` calling `a`

```
function b() {
   a();
}
```

is it good practice/bad practice/correct/wrong to have a `@throw` annotation over the definition of `b` indicating that `b` could throw that kind of exception?

Comment: PHPDoc was based on JavaDoc, and I'm pretty sure that in Java you would include the `@throws` declaration on your b() method here. But I think the more important question is whether you think it would be practically useful to you and other programmers to know that b() might throw a particular kind of exception, especially if it's one you might want to catch with a try/catch block when calling b().

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`@throws` annotation is to indicate for the developer if the function() can throw an exception
**First**, you have to ask the question : why don't catch the exception in `b()` method, is there a valid reason for that ?
**Yes ?** so you must add `@throws` annotation, it will indicate you, or others developers that using function() `b()` IS NOT SAFE and they will decide if they will
catch or propagate the exception 
**Also**, since **PHP** doesn't force you to catch an exception thrown by another function, the `@throws` annotation became a **must/mandatory** practice

Comment: Blindly catching exceptions because thery are "unsafe" is a bad attitude towards exceptions. The advantage of exceptions is that you can provide a clean code path for the success case and letting them propagate up the stack is an important part thereof. You don't explicitly deny that, but your answer suggests this (IMHO flawed) attitude towards them.

Answer (score 1):

As a matter of fact, `b()` throws exceptions. Whether that happens directly or indirectly is irrelevant to the caller. Now, the annotations are not supposed to document internal implementation details that may change or even vary with different derived classes. Rather, the annotations document the visible behaviour *for the caller*, so the *effective* exceptions should also be part of the annotations.